# BinarySearch toString

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I want to make a toString just like in the TreeSet.
For example my toString will print something like this:

```
Student{name='student1', dateOfBirth=2003-04-01, details='none'}, Student{name='student2', dateOfBirth=1999-05-11, details='none'},
```

But i want something like that:

```
[Student{name='student1', dateOfBirth=2003-04-01, details='none'}, Student{name='student2', dateOfBirth=1999-05-11, details='none'}]
```

My code:

```
 public String toString() {
        StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();
        inorderPrint(root, string);
        return string.toString();
    }

    private void inorderPrint(Node root, StringBuffer stringBuffer) {

        if (root != null) {
            inorderPrint(root.left, stringBuffer);
            stringBuffer.append(root.value.toString() +  ", ");
            inorderPrint(root.right, stringBuffer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a difference.  Can you specific exactly what you want to change in the output?  Also can you show the  `toString` method please.

Comment: The differences are in beggining  '[' and in the end ']' and there are not an ',' in the end too.

Comment: You could initialize the StringBuffer with a '[', append the closing ']' after the inorderPrint and prepend the comma, but only if the stringBuffer has more than 1 element (the opening bracket)

Comment: can you write this in my code,i dont kinda understand you

Comment: Pedantry incoming, I think you want `StringBuilder` because you don't need it to be `synchronized`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding extra characters like `[` `,` `]` you can use additional condition within inOrder traverse.

Sample code:

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();
    string.append('[');
    inorderPrint(root, string);
    string.append(']');
    return string.toString();
}

private void inorderPrint(Node root, StringBuffer stringBuffer)
{
    if (root != null)
    {
        inorderPrint(root.left, stringBuffer);
        stringBuffer.append(", ");
        stringBuffer.append(root.value.toString());
        stringBuffer.append(", ");
        inorderPrint(root.right, stringBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost correct. [] will print for each recursive call.

Comment: you're right. Modified the code. Added '[' before inOrder traversing and ']' after inOrder traversing.

Comment: Almost but thanks!